# Jssor Slider mobile compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After I added the scrolling logo\thumbnail slider, I encountered mobile compatibility issues when opening the page via mobile devices.

Seems like there is an issue with the `override: hidden` property and all the pages have shifted to the left while browsing via mobile devices.
http://tersertude.com/

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Add overflow: hidden for your #partners seems to fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you placed the slider in a parent container which has 15px padding at both left and right side.

Let's scale the width of slider to windows width - 30 then.

Please replace

```
//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (bodyWidth)
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 980));
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
```

with

```
//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    var availableWidth = bodyWidth - 30;
    if (bodyWidth)
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(availableWidth, 980));
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
```